# how to open an external application from widget in android?

Tags: android, widget

When we click the widget at that time i need to open an external aplication (for example netflix app).How to do this?

In all cases i find solutions like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589741/how-to-open-a-application-from-widget-in-android) but, is not what I'm looking.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969242/how-to-make-widget-of-running-application-in-android.

Comment: Then what do you want? Please post the exact requirement...

Comment: Please explain more...

Comment: Please explain what "not what I'm looking" means.

Comment: The exact requirement: open an external application from my own android widget. I edited the post to show an example. Obviously it's only the image, because i need open the real netflix application in the code.

Comment: When i say "not what I'm looking" i say that because in the typical solution, you need know the PackageName and the start activity name, to link the widget to the app. But i don't know this information for external apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create your own widget for external apps, you can use this code:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
      try
      {
       String packageName = "com.example.package";
       Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
       startActivity(launchIntent);
      }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
    }
```

So if you need the package name you can find it in a web browser, in google play site.
[image]

and then, just remplace it in the code: `String packageName = "com.netflix.mediaclient";`

Answer (score 2):

Try this but you should know the package name of that another application

```
  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  try
  {
   String packageName = "com.example.package";
   Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
   startActivity(launchIntent);
  }
catch (Exception e1)
{
}
```

EDIT:

To check the package name of the  application, open your file explorer and go to directory called android\data\   here you will find package names of all installed apps